# How do I change screen orientation in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, screen-orientation

How do we change emulator screen orientation to landscape or portrait?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator

Comment: Left Ctrl + F11 on windows7

Comment: Left Ctrl_F11 on Windows 8.1 too worked fine

Answer (score 463, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling

Comment: Numpad 7 is what I use, just make sure you have NumLock turned off so you're basically pressing the "Home" key on the Numpad.

Comment: Numpad 7 is nice, but if you're using a laptop, you're screwed, so this is the definite +1

Comment: on some linux distros the right Ctrl key may not functioning I use left Ctrl-F12 on archlinux

Comment: I thought this did not work for me and I kept searching and searching for other answers, but then I tried Ctrl-F12 again with the left Ctrl key instead of the right Ctrl key, and it worked!

Comment: On Mac it's CTRL + FN + F11

Comment: It shows sideways, but doesn't rotate the inner screen, on Nexus One avd.

Comment: turn on your auto rotate of emulator

Answer (score 84):

**Android Emulator Shortcuts**

<kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>     Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

<kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd>     Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

**1. Main Device Keys**

Home    Home Button

<kbd>F2</kbd>   Left Softkey / Menu / Settings button (or Page up)

<kbd>Shift+f2</kbd>     Right Softkey / Star button (or Page down)

<kbd>Esc</kbd>  Back Button

<kbd>F3</kbd>   Call/ dial Button

<kbd>F4</kbd>   Hang up / end call button

<kbd>F5</kbd>   Search Button

**2. Other Device Keys**

<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>  Volume up (or + on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off)
<kbd>Ctrl+F6</kbd>  Volume down (or + on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off)
<kbd>F7</kbd>   Power Button
<kbd>Ctrl+F3</kbd>  Camera Button

<kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>     Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

<kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd>     Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

<kbd>F8</kbd>   Toggle cell network

<kbd>F9</kbd>   Toggle code profiling

<kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>    Toggle fullscreen mode

<kbd>F6</kbd>   Toggle trackball mode

Comment: With only two modes changing forward and backwards comes out the same. Also as source one could cite http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling

Answer (score 40):

For those pesky Apple MacBook keyboard layouts that otherwise adjust the volume, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 18):

Num <kbd>7</kbd> on keypad does it for me. Remember it works only when <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is off.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on Mac to change the landscape to portrait and vice versa.

<kbd>left-ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Windows 7.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Linux.

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> both work.

Answer (score 14):

Additionally, you must verify the autorotate setting on the emulator. Because of if this setting is off, you can't change the orientation besides press the rotate buttons. In the following picture, I will show how you can do this.

[image: Activate Autorotate Setting]

Comment: You just saved my life. I totally forgot about that. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm happy can help you, greetings Vinicius

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu none of the keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>numpad 7</kbd>/<kbd>numpad 9</kbd>) worked for me. But I can rotate the emulator sending the keys with **xdotool**.

For example for a VM named "Galaxy_Nexus" I can rotate the emulator with:

```
xdotool search --name "Galaxy" key "ctrl_L+F11"
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked in my case, without the L.
xdotool search --name "Nexus" key "ctrl+F11"

Comment: All other methods failed on Linux Mint 17.3, this works. I also had to modify the key to "ctrl+F11"

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>numpad 7</kbd> and <kbd>numpad 9</kbd> don't work on my [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) box, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> does.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac, use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

​​​​

Answer (score 6):

You no longer need to remember the shortcuts. The latest Android AVD interface contains a sidebar with various functional shortcuts. I've circled in blue the buttons that rotate the screen clockwise and counter-clockwise.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, although this rotates the emulator depiction, it doesn't signal the applications to rotate.

Comment: @Oscar I'm using Flutter's MediaQuery and my app rotates. There's a short lag but then the mode has changed.

Comment: @Oscar it is signaling but you need to swipe "a finger" from the top of the display and click on the enable rotation icon. I guess the emulator comes with Android system that has the icon disabled by default. Imagine how you would enable/disable rotation on your android phone. See the answer by martosfre above.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
DELL Latitude E6320

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + (double tap on <kbd>F12</kbd>)

Answer (score 3):

Fn + 7 is a solution for keyboards where the num keypad is merged with the main keypad. Here the key with 7 (and &) is the key that has the blue-coloured 7.

Answer (score 3):

Android Emulator Shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

Ctrl+F12 Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

1. Main Device Keys

<kbd>Home</kbd> Home Button

<kbd>F2</kbd> Left Softkey / Menu / Settings button (or <kbd>Page up</kbd>)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Right Softkey / Star button (or <kbd>Page down</kbd>)

<kbd>Esc</kbd> Back Button

<kbd>F3</kbd> Call/ dial Button

<kbd>F4</kbd> Hang up / end call button

<kbd>F5</kbd> Search Button

2. Other Device Keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> Volume up (or <kbd>+</kbd> on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> Volume down (or <kbd>+</kbd> on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off) <kbd>F7</kbd> Power Button <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> Camera Button

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

<kbd>F8</kbd> Toggle cell network

<kbd>F9</kbd> Toggle code profiling

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> Toggle fullscreen mode

<kbd>F6</kbd> Toggle trackball mode

Answer (score 3):

On **Android Studio 4.0.1**, the emulator includes buttons for rotation.

In the image below, the Rotate Left (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd>) button is outlined in blue and the Rotate Right (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd>) button is outlined in red.

[image: Android Emulator]

After pressing one of the buttons to rotate, the orientation of the application itself will not change. For instance, if we pressed Rotate Left, the application would look this:

[image: Android Emulator Rotated Left]

To change the orientation of the running application, it is necessary to click the icon outlined in red above. Note that this icon may take a few seconds to show up and will disappear shortly. Also, when rotating back to portrait orientation, one must press the opposite rotate button for the icon to appear. This means that if we pressed Rotate Left, we need to press Rotate Right to return to the original orientation, and vice versa.

[image: Android Emulator Landscape]

Answer (score 2):

In my notebook, Dell Latitude E4310, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> keys do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>function</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> for HP laptops. Others keys specified in previous answers didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

My virtual device could not be rotated.
Go to the device list, click settings and change the predefined resolution.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> = For Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

To do this on the Surface

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

With Android Studio:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Arrow</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

All of the above methods didn't work for me. Using <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><Windows Key></kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> worked on [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 17.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Super</kbd>-><kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>-><kbd>F12</kbd> works for me on Fedora 23

Answer (score 0):

In the updated emulator you don't have to remember the keyboard shortcuts -- they have added a side panel to the right side of the window. You can change the screen orientation by clicking either of the "rotate" buttons in that side panel.

[image]

Just click on Rotate button to change the landscape to portrait and vice versa.

Comment: Unfortunately, although this rotates the emulator depiction, it doesn't signal the applications to rotate. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac to see the help: `⌘/` then you will see Keyboard shortcuts.

Rotate right: `⌘→` , Rotate left: `⌘←`

Answer (score 0):

For Linux use: **Right_Ctrl + left_Arrow** or **Right_Ctrl + right_Arrow**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure Auto-rotate is ON

[image: 1]

2. Rotate Right/Left.

[image: 2]

Answer (score -2):

Ctrl+Left

See documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#tasks

[image]