# Switching to landscape mode in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is probably a pretty easy to answer question, but I can't find the solution myself after a couple hours of searching the documentation and Google. I set the orientation of my Android app to `landscape` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

However, when I run the app in the simulator, it appears sideways and in portrait mode. How can I switch the emulator to `landscape` mode on a `mac`? It's running the 1.6 SDK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17161332 this will surely help you a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change screen orientation in the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991318/how-do-i-change-screen-orientation-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 636, accepted):

Try:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on Mac to change the landscape to portrait and vice versa.
- <kbd>left-ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Windows 7.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Linux.

For Mac users, you only need to use the <kbd>fn</kbd> key if the setting "Use all <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> etc. keys as function keys" (under System Preferences -> Keyboard) is checked.

- <kbd>left-ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Windows 7 
  It works fine in Windows 7 for android emulator to change the landscape orientation to portrait and vice versa.

Comment: ctrl+fn+F11 on a Macbook Pro didn't work, but Keypad 7 and Keypad 9 does. HOWEVER, the rotation works once. It will orient to lanscape, but when returning to portrait, the screen doesn't redraw in the portrait mode.

Comment: Although it is relatively obvious the windows shortcut is Crtl + F11

Comment: control+fn+F11 does work on my Macbook Pro Retina display...everytime.

Comment: [ctrl+f11] works on my Macbook Pro OS X Lion (10.7.5)  [ctrl+fn+f11] DOES NOT.

Comment: So simple! Is there an overview of key commands for the emulator somewhere?

Comment: Ctrl + F11 didn't work for me on Linux, however, KEYPAD_7 did!

Comment: [left-ctrl] + [F11] works on my Kubuntu Linux 13.10 (right-ctrl don't) - oh the joy

Comment: Simple, right to the core. You deserve more than +1.

Comment: Pressing ctrl-F11 or ctrl-F12 on OSX rotates the window, but the content doesn't adjust its orientation to be readable; it stays sideways with the rotation of the window.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your layout is not set to rotate.
Some of you don't need to hold fn on a mac because you've changed the default function of the F- keys from accessing functions.

Comment: Ctrl-Fn-F11, seriously?! Would it kill Google to add this to the emulator menu?

Comment: left-ctrl F11 on Windows is bringing up some sort of measurement tool. The emulator has a side menu of rotation buttons, but they do nothing.

Answer (score 82):

Not sure about your question - "sideways" is the same as "landscape".

If you mean how to switch during runtime:

- Switch to previous layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape):
  KEYPAD_7, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Switch to next layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape):
  KEYPAD_9, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).

Comment: Tried this, has no effect on the emulator for me (on a Macbook).

Comment: Not even ctrl+f11 and ctrl+f12?

Hm, can you try pressing the "fn" key followed by "7" or "9"?

Comment: Figured it out. Have to do: ctrl+fn+F11

Comment: And if that doesn't work try, ctrl+cmd+F11. There is a slight lag while the app resets.

Comment: On my case windows live 7 cmd = (thw window key) Thanks @Gary Rowe

Comment: Because there's no incentive for askers to mark answers correct here!  That's why there's hundreds of thousands of unmarked answers.

Answer (score 28):

Just use <kbd>9</kbd> in numeric keyboard with num-lock off.

[image: Image showing the numpad with 9 highlighted]

7 rotates in the opposite  direction.

Answer (score 10):

[image: AVD Auto-rotation]

It will cost 4 hours of researching. Don't forget enable auto-rotation in your virtual devices!

Comment: Thanks! As a note for others, this setting in Android 33 is under Settings > Accessibility > System Controls.

Answer (score 9):

Android Emulator Shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

1. Main Device Keys

<kbd>Home</kbd> Home Button

<kbd>F2</kbd> Left Softkey / Menu / Settings button (or <kbd>PgUp</kbd>)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Right Softkey / Star button (or <kbd>PgDn</kbd>)

<kbd>Esc</kbd> Back Button

<kbd>F3</kbd> Call/ dial Button

<kbd>F4</kbd> Hang up / end call button

<kbd>F5</kbd> Search Button

2. Other Device Keys

<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> Volume up (or + on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off) Ctrl+F6 Volume down (or + on numeric keyboard with Num Lock off) <kbd>F7</kbd> Power Button <kbd>Ctrl+F3</kbd> Camera Button

<kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

<kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

<kbd>F8</kbd> Toggle cell network

<kbd>F9</kbd> Toggle code profiling

<kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> Toggle fullscreen mode

<kbd>F6</kbd> Toggle trackball mode

Comment: Android Studio 4.0 with Ctrl + F11 and Ctrl + F12 now utilizes multi-finger swiping instead of changing orientation of the device that is being emulated.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>  to change the orientation of the android emulator on windows

Answer (score 4):

On iMac with long keyboard (keyboard with numeric keypad at the right):

```
(1) Cmd + 7 (on numeric part of keyboard)
(2) Cmd + 9 (on numeric part of keyboard)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Android Studio and none of the suggestions worked. I can turn the emulator but it stays in portrait. I didn't want to add a command in the manifest forcing landscape. The fix for me was:

1. turn the emulator to landscape mode using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> (the image will still be in portrait though)
2. Open up the camera in the os, it opens up in landscape mode, the only app that does this
3. without doing anything else, debug my app from Android Studio and now it shows up in landscape

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a emulator running eclipse, apparently its a known issue with API19. For more and some work arounds:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964833/android-emulator-not-rotating-to-landscape

Answer (score 4):

This is now much more intuitive. The AVD interface now includes a sidebar with various functional shortcuts. The buttons circled in blue will rotate the device clockwise and counterclockwise on the screen.

[image]

Comment: Those buttons do nothing. If they actually worked, I wouldn't need to google for a fix to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just a little bug (Bug for me) I found on mac emulator.

On changing the orientation to landscape (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>) it changes to landscape but content shows in portrait format.for that:

Go to emulator: Settings-> Display->When device is rotated->Rotate the contents of the screen

Answer (score 3):

I have found that sometimes the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> combination just doesn't do it for me.
I have solved it by disabling the keyboard input in the emulator settings.

To do that, go to your emulator settings, klick the "show advanced settings" button and scroll all the way down. Then, disable the "enable keyboard input" option.

After doing that, try to start your emulator again, and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> combination should work.

[image: enable keyboard input option]

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways to move landscape on Android Emulator:

### 1. Mac:

- `Ctrl + Fn + F11`
- `Keypad 7`  or `Keypad 9`
- `Ctrl + F12`  or  `Ctrl + Fn + F12`
- `Command + 7`  or  `Command + 9`

### 2. Windows:

- `Left Ctrl + F11`  or  `Ctrl + F12`

### 3. Linux:

- `Ctrl + F11`

### 4. Android studio :

We can write `screenOrientation = "landscape"` in the `androidManifest.xml` file.

### 5. Keyboard:

in side the emulator, turn off the Num-Lock and press `Keypad 7`  and  `Keypad 9`.

### 6. Emulator:

- click the rotate button on the screen shown below.

[image]

- click the rotate button on the screen shown below.

  [image]

Comment: The images no longer exist @NoviceProgrammer!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> works wonderfully on Ubuntu / Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2):

following for different plateform

WINDOWS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

LINUX: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

MAC OS X: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (or <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>, depending on your keyboard configuration)

Answer (score 1):

for windows try left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key with <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> or Num off 7

Answer (score 1):

The complete listing is buried in the android docs, and i only found it via google / dogpile.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

`That link has the emulator shortcut keys as of right now.`

`=\`

Answer (score 1):

To rotate the Android Emulator, just disable the Num Lock key and and use the 7 and the 9 in the num pad to rotate the emulator and change its layout from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 1):

10 years later, I run into the same problem... For me, the issue is that it was literally disabled in my emulator.

Go to the running emulator, and drag down from the top menu area to make it show the action buttons and notifications.  Those action buttons show what features are enabled/disabled, like Wifi, airplane mode, and....rotate.

In my emulator, the 3rd button from the left was the "rotate" button, and it was gray.  Once I tapped on it to toggle it on, boom, my app would now switch to landscape mode when I rotated it.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> will do. There's no need for "command" key

Answer (score 0):

In my windows-8 laptop, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> works.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> also works well on linux(ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your hardware keyboard is enable while creating your AVD

-launch the emulator
-install your app
-launch your app
-make sure that your Num lock is on
-Press '7' &'9' from your num pad to change your orientation landscape to portrait & portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i succeeded by doing this:

1- enable 'Auto-Rotate', if it isn´t yet. 
2- either use rotation left-right option at panel located next to the virtual device, or click (ctrl + left/right arrow key), in order to rotate the device.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the emulator click down at the top and drag down to bring down the menu.  the fourth button from the left (Arrows) is the rotate lock. If it is grey click it and it will turn blue.

Then you can click the rotate phone icon on the right-hand sidebar of the emulator and your screen will rotate.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I know that your app is started with "landscape" and Emulator is portrait.

This is because your emu start setting is portrait.

For change the setting of existed Emu, you can go to avd config to change your setting. For example, I have an emu "Pixel_C_API_33", so I can update by following command.

```
vi $HOME/.android/avd/Pixel_C_API_33.avd/config.ini
```

Change

```
hw.initialOrientation=Portrait
```

To

```
hw.initialOrientation=Landscape
```

Next time when you start your emu, it will be "Landscape".

[image: emu landscape]

Answer (score -1):

For those of you with a Chromebook Pixel/Ubuntu/Crouton with no numpad, installing the `onboard` keyboard worked for me.

[image: image of onboard software keyboard on ubuntu]

Just press <kbd>123</kbd> to access the numpad layout, and then press <kbd>7</kbd>

If you're on Unity already, `onboard` may already be installed, so just type `onboard` from your command line to see if it's there.

If not, just type:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install onboard
```

*PS: The Chromebook Pixel's upper keys were supposed to represent the traditional <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F11</kbd> function keys on Ubuntu/Crouton, so you may want to try those special hardware keys first (on their own or in combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). It's just that for me, I'm running an old copy of Crouton, and the only function key that seems to be recognized is <kbd>F6</kbd>*

Answer (score -1):

If you can not switch to landscape(or portrait) while using ctr+f11/12 
Maybe the virtual device (android phone) itself lock the rotation.
Going to the android control center (pull down on the home page), and unlock.

Comment: this question is for the emulator not for a real phone - ctrl + f11/12 is also allready proposed

Comment: of course this question is about rotation on the emulator , virtual phone could also lock the rotation switch, and that is a default setting , I came across this situation.and the keyboard control doesnt work .

Answer (score -6):

To switch to Landscape mode in android emulator u have 2 ways to accomplish.

1> You can create a relative layout such that when you switch from one mode to other it will change accordingly

2> You can create 2 separate XML file both the views and use it whenever required