# Switching the Emulator to landscape mode in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is not a duplicate of [Switching to landscape mode in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator) because in that question the platform is a Mac and I am using an ubuntu. I am not able to switch to landscape mode in my emulator- I tried all the solutions from that question,that is using keypad 7 or 9 from the emulator keyboard or pressing ctrl-F11. I guess I am missing something...

Thanks.

Edit: I am using Android 2.2 as my platform in my emulator in eclipse indigo.

Comment: Ctrl-F11 works for me in Ubuntu...

Answer (score 4):

The proper keys are **Ctrl-F11** or **Keypad-7**
(Tested on Ubuntu 11.04, using Eclipse Indigo and Andriod 2.2)
See documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

It is possible you have a system keyboard shortcut bound to Ctrl-F11.  Or that your numlock key is in the wrong state preventing the keypad shortcut from working.

Also, if you launch the camera app the display will rotate to landscape:

```
I/WindowManager(   70): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut does not work in my system (Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit). But I can rotate the emulator sending the keys with **xdotool**.

If the emulator window title has the text "Galaxy" you can send a CTRL+F11 with:

```
xdotool search --name "Galaxy" key "ctrl+F11"
```

Answer (score 1):

CTRL-Fll and CTRL-F12 ended up not working for me either, the same to be used for some KDE short cuts. Keypad 7 and 9 worked for me, in KDE.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer. I am sure you all have used right Ctrl, so it is not working with right Ctrl but it is working with left Ctrl. I have tested it on ubuntu. Check it for yours. and please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Fedora with KDE and frustratingly enough, KDE is sucking up  and  and I can't figure out where to turn it off.  Right or left  doesn't make any difference.  On my laptop I can get keypad 7 by pressing my FN key and pressing 7 and that works fine.  Oh, wait, one of my desktop effects was using  (the rotating cube).  I turned that off.  I still can't figure out about