# 2.2 emulator in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode) i have same problem, i also follow defined solution but i cant get success to view horizontally Landscape mode. any idea why this thing accure?

manifest file ::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.saneshApp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".saneshApp" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity android:name=".animation_page" ></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Update::
[image]

**Update**
[image]

Comment: Are you using android vnc viewer? I don't understand what you want to do. You say this in your manifests `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` why do you expect to see portrait mode?

Comment: no , i am use android default avd 2.2

Comment: What is landscape? Do you want to use landscape? Do you want to use portrait? Do you want to change the orientation of the emulator? You do that by pressing ctrl + f12.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean your emulator is not in landscape mode? Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator can help you.

Comment: i have press ctrl + f12 but no effect in emulator, it is same display in link

Comment: i want to display it only landscape mode

Comment: From your image, seems like your application IS already looked in landscape mode.

Comment: ya you are right but it is not look horizontally portrait. it is currently looking in vertically portrait

Comment: i would like to show my app, you can show in second image.

Comment: Then, I understand your problem is not with the application(there is nothing to do in your manifest), but just with the emulator, so refer to my previous link; did you try all the option suggested in the comments there?

Comment: are you not able to rotate the emulator?

Comment: Can anyone explain the problem? I'm not sure that I understand what the OP want to do.

Comment: @Kaj You already answered according to his very problem: the emulator is not rotating to landscape mode. It might be some other problem with his OS or his keyboard, maybe a reboot can solve that, but I don't think it might be another solution beside that you already provided, with the Emulator settings link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ctrl+f12 to rotate the emulator. One think use left ctrl key because right ctrl key will not work for rotate the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can find keyboard mappings here:
[Emulator settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)

Scroll down on that page. You change orientation by pressing CTRL+F12

Comment: i have also try it firstbut cant..., any way i have update my question please see it