# How to switch the browser into landscape mode in an Android emulator

Tags: android, web-applications

I was writing a web app for Android which can be used in both landscape/portrait mode.

I read about this question:
[Switching to landscape mode in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator)

And successfully rotated the screen into "landscape mode".

But unluckily, the browser was rotated *WITH* the screen too,
like no gravity sensory was working.

Please, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

p.s. I was using a standalone Android SDK, without any IDE. Target ROM ver is 2.3.3  .

Comment: p.s. I was switching p/l mode with hotkey "ctrl+F11".

Comment: Problem solved. I changed the rom into ver 2.1. Now the browser remains vertical while in landscape mode. Maybe there is something wrong with the 2.3 rom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ctrl + F11 and Ctrl + F12

it should work. if not close the emulator and sart it again.

Make sure you don't have code snippets prevents Landscape view in both code base and Manifest file.

Comment: I think he's talking about the android web browser. He's mentioned the word browser in his question. If so, its got nothing to do with the manifest file.

Comment: I thought he is using a WebView. in dat case my answer doesn't add much value interms of code snippet and manifest file.

Comment: Problem solved. I changed the rom into ver 2.1. Now the browser remains vertical while in landscape mode. Maybe there is something wrong with the 2.3 rom.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl+F12. That just might work.

Edit: If you are on a PC, I think you need to use left ctrl.

For a Mac, ctrl+fn+F12