# How to change my emulator from portrait to landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I did not find any setting in eclipse while creating the AVD or when it was running any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Ctrl-F12 is the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

> ### Switch to previous/next layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)
>
> On Windows
>
> - <kbd>left-Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>)
> - <kbd>KP7</kbd> or <kbd>KP9</kbd>
>
> On Mac (depending on your keyboard configuration):
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>)
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + (<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>)
> - <kbd>KP7</kbd> or <kbd>KP9</kbd>
>
> On Linux
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>)
> - <kbd>KP7</kbd> or <kbd>KP9</kbd>

Reference:

1. [Switching to landscape mode in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator)
2. [Android emulator keyboard mapping](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping)

Comment: Why just copying and pasting the answer? instead you can provide a link as a comment

Comment: [ctrl+f11] works on my Macbook Pro OS X Lion (10.7.5) [ctrl+fn+f11] DOES NOT.

Comment: @GopalRao sorry I'm new here. I need 50 rep to leave a comment. Now it's look ok?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

`ctrl + F11` or `ctrl + F12`

[How do I rotate the Android emulator display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to change orientation

Answer (score 0):

for windows try left Ctrl key with F11 or F12 or Num off 7