# landscape mode not working in Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

The following sample is from the project https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-navigation, and layout file is from https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-navigation/tree/master/app/src/main/res

I test it in Android Studio Emulator with both portrait and landscape mode, you can see the result at *A1.png* and *A2.png*.

It seems that landscape mode doesn't work in Android Studio Emulator.

I test the same code in real mobile phone, you can see the result at *B1.png* and *B2.png*

The landscape mode works well in real mobile phone, what problem with Android Studio Emulator when I use landscape mode?

BTW, I have read the article [Switching to landscape mode in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator)

**navigation_activity.xml**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.codelabs.navigation.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**navigation_activity.xml （h470dp）**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.codelabs.navigation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**navigation_activity.xml （w960dp）**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.codelabs.navigation.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/nav_view"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/nav_view"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**A1.png**

[image]

**A2.png**

[image]

**B1.png**

[image]

**B2.png**

[image]

**Added Content**

To No Name: Thanks!

I test by your way, it seems that the emulator with landscape mode in Android Studio 3.5 doesn't work well yet.

The menu icon in real mobile phone with landscape mode isn't displayed in the emulator with landscape mode, you can see *C1.png*, why? and *B2.png* is real mobile phone with landscape mode

**C1.png**
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you need to set also the rotation inside the device in the bottom right part after you click the rotation left/ rotation right in the emulator control.

**Before**

[image]

**after**
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: can I ask why there's a hamburger style "only in the landscape orientation"? Do you add it in your code?

Comment: What is the point of having to click two buttons for rotating the device AND screen?

Comment: I don't have the icon in the bottom right. why??