# Android Emulator - Screen orientation does not work properly

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-orientation, android-virtual-device

I created a virtual Android device, `480x800`, ran it, and as I already found how to change the screen `orientation` (portrait-landscape, <kbd>CTRL+F11</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL+F12</kbd>/<kbd>KP7</kbd>/<kbd>KP9</kbd>), I used these keys to change the `orientation`.

But when I try one of these keys, the virtual screen rotates 90 degrees, but the orientation does not change. Hence, the Buttons are vertically placed on the screen, and all the text too. Just like a picture that is getting rotated 90 degrees.

How do I get the virtual degrees to actually switch over to the other layout file `(/res/layout-land/activity_entry.xml)`? Eclipse's graphical viewer does switching between `landscape/portrait` correctly.

**EDIT**
I added this part in the activity right under this the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`
method, but the application does not recognize screen orientation change:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { 
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Orientation changed";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

**EDIT 2**
When I call `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` from within the `onCreate()` method, it works nicely.

Comment: I think it is Ctrl+F11 and Ctrl+F12, try this

Comment: Ctrl+F12, will obviously work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991318/how-to-change-emulator-screen-orientation

Comment: Remove android:screenOrientation if you set it in your activity in android manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off number lock and then press <kbd>7</kbd> or press <kbd>9</kbd> and check emulator's orientation is changed and other way to change orientation of emulator is press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd>.

Comment: both KP9 and KP7 rotate the AVD 90 degrees, but the screen isn't rearranged, everything is just 90 degrees rotated, like an image

Comment: Why is this considered an answer to the question?   It doesn't matter whether you hit CTRL F12 or Num Pad 7 or Num Pad 9 or ....   The emulator program rotates, but the application doesn't get notified.

Comment: I've tried it with the simplest possible hello world app on multiple releases of Android with or without Google API's.  With or without hardware keyboard enabled.  With or with snapshots. With or without using the GPU.   With Eclipse or with Android studio.  It just doesn't work!  (it used to long ago.)

Answer (score 4):

check in settings tab if auto rotated is enabled, if it's turned off turn it on, then whenever you click rotation button it will rotate by himself

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have set any android:screenOrientation in the Manifest file for that acitvity. If yes, remove it and check.

If not working, it seems like a bug reported in android issues forums. Check [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17963)

Comment: But once you remove it, the activity will be destryoed and recreated upon orientation change. To make the activity handle the change without a recreate, use `android:configChanges` attribute in the manifest.

Comment: I dont have that set. For any activity. Also, i did try KP7/KP9 and CTRL+11/12, but to no avail.

Comment: Try clicking 7 after making number lock off.

Answer (score 1):

You may find, like I did that the orientation change was actually effected but the screen only changed a few seconds later than you would expect. In other words, the answer might be "patience grasshopper."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently and the answer provided here did not solve it. However I found this post:

[Android emulator not rotating to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964833/android-emulator-not-rotating-to-landscape)

Which mentions that there is a bug in some of the emulator targets (19 for example which I was using).

Simply changing the target to 17 made the rotation start working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First need to check in manifeast file you are setting `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` if yes then remove it. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Cold booting android emulator helps me to resolve the orientation not working issue.
[image]