# Android emulator not rotating to landscape

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-orientation

When i try to switch the orientation of my emulator, the **emulator window** rotates and the **orientation of the emulator screen** stays as it were. Can anyone tell me **what is the reason for this**?I have tried all the answers from StackOverflow and nothing seem to help
[image: This is how the emulator screen looks like when i try to change the orientation]

Comment: press 9 on keyboard and put off ur num lock

Comment: Opening the camera app appears to force the UI to re-orient.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Some of the emulator targets like 4.4 (API level 19) and 2.3 have a bug.  Change your emulator to target version 4.2 or 4.3 and try to change the orientation.

See the history of this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

Related question: [Impossible to rotate the emulator with android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4)

Comment: For those who need a work around for this issue please refer trakos answer . http://stackoverflow.com/a/22752753/2636887

Comment: I've found that the "ordinary" API 19 x86 image has this bug, but the "Google APIs" x86 version works fine.

Answer (score 10):

If everything else fails (it did for me), as a workaround you can use application for screen orientation.
In the other question ([Impossible to rotate the emulator with android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726285/impossible-to-rotate-the-emulator-with-android-4-4)), user vldmrrr wrote that:

> Until it is fixed I use this free application "Set Orientation".
>   Install the apk into emulator using adb install.

The application displays a shortcut in the notification status bar.
(I know it's an old question, but it's pretty high in google).

Answer (score 2):

With the android L emulator you can go into landscape by opening your app, then opening the camera app (you will need to set an emulated camera in AVD) record a video. Then press ctr-f12 of 11. In the camera app click the video thumbnail and play it back. The video should go to landscape. Then press the multitasking button and multitask into your app. DO NOT GO TO THE HOME SCREEN OR YOU WILL HAVE TO GO INTO THE CAMERA APP, GO TO LANDSCAPE AND REPLAY THE VIDEO! please let me know if this works for any other android emulator versions.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to enable the accelerometer in the device profile.

Answer (score 0):

These answers help me to do this.. Please try these and you can see what u wanted to do

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057309/1063861

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535315/1063861

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in android emulator. Add Keyboard Support - yes in emulator properties to fix this problem. You can track this bug : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34237

Comment: i'm using android sdk tools R22.0.4 keyboard support is already set in this version

Answer (score 0):

Other answers cover this pretty well, but there seem to be some restrictions on using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key bindings (at least in Linux).

#### Summary: Key bindings for changing emulator orientation

*Note that there are relevant bugs for emulator targets [v2.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189) and [v4.4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34237). See the bug reports for more info and workarounds.*

Emulator shortcuts are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping).

- Prev Layout: <kbd>KEYPAD_7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-F11</kbd>
- Next Layout: <kbd>KEYPAD_9</kbd> or  <kbd>Ctrl-F12</kbd>

#### Notes on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key bindings (in Linux)

- Although the docs claim <kbd>Ctrl-F11/12</kbd> work, I've found that these bindings only work using the *left* control key (<kbd>LeftCtrl-F11/12</kbd>). Someone mentioned this happening in Windows, so it's not just Linux.
- <kbd>LeftCtrl-F11/12</kbd> using a key remapped to <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd> doesn't work for me. I need to use the physical <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd> key. I don't know whether this affects non-X11 systems as well.

#### Note on <kbd>KP_n</kbd> key bindings

- Keep in mind that a few numeric keypads actually emit scancodes for the number-row digits, rather than the proper keypad digits. Such keypads won't work for any keypad-specific bindings.

Answer (score -1):

you can try in two ways.

1.left ctrl+F11

2.enable num lock then press 9.

Comment: as i said earlier only the emulator 'window' rotates and not the orientation,my guess is that the orientation sensor in the platform might be having some issue

Answer (score -2):

Is only your application is not rotating or other applications in the emulator also not rotating?

If only your application is not rotating, then there must be android:screenOrientation parameter set somewhere in the manifest file.

If all other apps on the emulator are also not rotating, no problem with your application, delete and create a new emulator..

Comment: The problem is not with my application,the bug is with the **emulator**

Answer (score -3):

Check in your manifest if there is android:screenOrientation

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.your.activity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
    </activity>
```

If this is the case, delete the lines.

Answer (score -8):

try pressing numpad 7 ... it will rotate your emulator screen.