# Changing Orientation in Bluestacks to test Orientation Change of my App

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-testing, bluestacks

Android Emulator 4.4 apparently [has a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964833/android-emulator-not-rotating-to-landscape/22752753#22752753) which keeps it from changing rotation appropriately. Having heard that Bluestacks is faster anyway, I wanted to give it a shot, but I can't find a way to *change my orientation while in my app*. My app launches in the full tablet-sized screen of Bluestacks and that's that. The system tray options don't help. I want Bluestacks to look and behave like a standard android phone, with the ability to rotate.

It looks like other versions of Bluestacks have had a rotation button (and other buttons)? I find references to this, but it's not in the latest version I downloaded. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: If you right click blue stacks icon in the system tray is there an option to rotate there? I use GenyMotion personally, but it has to be able to rotate somehow.

Comment: No, there are options to enable rotation for portrait apps, but they don't seem to do anything, at least in the context I'm using them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the icon on the system tray, setting it to enabled worked for me. 
You also have to check if you are forcing the portrait orientation on your manifest. I had to put the tag on every Activity tag, not on the application tag. Like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
   </activity>
```