# Strange landscape orientation error (whatever android api)

Tags: android, ubuntu, rotation, emulation

When I rotate android emulator (with Ctrl+F11 on Kubuntu), the emulator is indeed rotated, but not the inside screen. I've deleted my avds several times (and rebuild new instances), with different skins/configurations, I've even edited the skin file (hardware-qemu.ini) ... without success.

Has someone run into a similar problem ? (I knew that some users had only this problem with Android kitkat images, but for me it is with all android api !!!) ?

Android sdk tools : 24.0.2

Extra : Android Studio 1.0.2

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964833/android-emulator-not-rotating-to-landscape

Comment: Thanks but even with jelly bean (4.2), I can't rotate emulator properly. Maybe because of KDE system ?

Comment: try opening Camera app on emulator, this was one if the tips to force emulator to re-orient.

Comment: Camera application has a bug on my emulator (stops immediately), and it come back to portrait very fast. But even if it worked, it could not be the solution, as the application I am developping need to be tested with a "suddenly" changed orientation mode.

Comment: There is an app which seems to have worked for those where no other solution was success: Give it a try. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation

Comment: Thanks. I would like to, but I can't launch playstore on my android emulator. Is there a workaround ? A downloadable apk ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68752/discussion-between-aadtechnical-and-laurent-bernabe).

Answer (score 0):

You can try following options;some of them have worked in most cases (depending on Windows vs Linux machine used for running Emulator).

1. Disable the "Hardware keyboard present" check-box in the "Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD)" window.

2.Try opening "Camera" app on emulator, this was one if the tips to force emulator to re-orient.

3.Set "accelerometer" Property of Emulator to true. (Open AVD Manager -> GoTo 'Device Definitions' tab -> Select an existing AVD -> Clone)

4. Install the free application "Set Orientation". Install the apk into emulator using "adb install"
   Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation