# Changing View of Android Application instead of Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-view, android-virtual-device

[image]

With reference to the picture , The App view is tilted, seems like it is not straight, You can see the App Name as well `Jaago` which is titled, I changed the AVD postions from Landscape to Potrait and ViceVersa ,but that doesn't effect my App View at all..Any help in this regard.
The HomeScreen
[image]

Comment: Check out in manifest file whether it might have given fixed orientation.

Comment: @GrIsHu works fine on my PC and mobile as well, In other PC it shows like this

Comment: Then it may be the issue of AVD orientation for the screen.

Comment: Try to create new AVD and check out in that.

Comment: @GrIsHu I tried that..

Comment: Can you post your application manifest file ?

Comment: @GrIsHu I dont think that have to deal with menifest file because even the Android standard Home screen and Menu with all apps shows titled

Comment: I think this link can help you [changing the orientation of emulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991318/how-to-change-emulator-screen-orientation

Comment: @Pushpendra its somethhing inside the emulator, emulator direction wouldn't matter. The User clearly wrote in his question

Comment: @user1765876 can you post a screen shot of your emulator configuration? and if possible screen shots of home and menu screens of your emulator as well.

Comment: Try to disabling `Hardware keyboard present` or removing "Keyboard lid support" for your emulator (using AVD Manager & edit avd)

Comment: @MohanKrishna please have a look

Comment: @SherifelKhatib it works but what was the reason?

Comment: @user1765876 check the answer. It is not really clear why.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

*Add these lines in your Android Manifest file after declaring **all activities** in activity tags **

like:

```
  <activity android:name="com.geeklabs.ActivityMain"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

May be it will helps you.

Comment: what does this have to do

Comment: This will used for not getting exceptions while changing screen orientation when performing any operations.This allows to preventing the unfortunately stopping exception if you change the screen orientation

Answer (score 1):

Try to disabling "Hardware keyboard present" or removing "Keyboard lid support" for your emulator.

You can do this by going to the AVD Manager & editing the emulator you are using.

---

The reason for this might be related to the following bugs:

- [Issue 13189:    Orientation does not change from landscape to portrait on Emulator on 2.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189)
- [Issue 19910:    [Emulator] startActivityForResult on camera - Screen orientation remains fixed in landscape after taking picture](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19910)
- [Issue 874:  manifest screen orientation and run config emulator screen orientation don't work together](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=874)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the Android emulator running 2.3

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189