# After upgrading to Android Studio 2.0, I cannot change the screen orientation in the Android emulator

Tags: android-studio

Recently I upgraded the Android Studio from `1.5.x` to `2.0` stable version.

Before the upgrade I was changing the screen orientation with the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** + **<kbd>F12</kbd>** or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** + **<kbd>F11</kbd>** keyboard shortcut but now it doesn't work in the `2.0` version. I also tried **<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>** and **<kbd>Numpad 9</kbd>** (with the numpad on or off) but without success.

Yes, I'm aware that *the new Android AVD interface contains a sidebar with various functional shortcuts which includes `Rotate left (Ctrl + Left)` and `Rotate right (Ctrl + Right)` icons* but it rotate only the the device not the mode (Landscape or Portrait) as it showed in the image below:

[image: Rotate right]

*How can I change emulator screen orientation to landscape or portrait in the new Android Studio 2.0?*

**P.S.** Please do not mark my question as duplicate, I tried all the solutions from [How do I change screen orientation in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991318/how-do-i-change-screen-orientation-in-the-android-emulator) and [How to rotate the Android emulator display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display) as those questions were valid for earlier versions of Android Studio.

**P.P.S.** I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 operating system on a Samsung R530 notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading my operating system from *Ubuntu 14.04* to *Ubuntu 16.04* the bug disappeared and the `Rotate left (Ctrl + Left)` and `Rotate right (Ctrl Right)` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug. Please check out https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206262 and report the observed behavior.

**Edit:** Fixed in SDK Tools 25.1.6

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real solution, but if anything don't work, it's good workaround. Just add screenOrientation property to activity in the Manifest file.

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"           
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
 />
```