# Downloading latest Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

My current Android Studio installation (linux-64bit) is showing a pop-up saying there is a new Version of Android Studio 2.

I am unable to download the current stable of Android Studio.
The download-link (on big green button) reffers to the Terms and Conditions. If i Accept and klick the button (which is showing no text, which is also strange) it redirects me to the index page again.

Here is the index page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Have they withdrawn the release or something? Does anybody know a direct-link?

Thank you for any help on it

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34013949/3480829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a little patience and try to check for update from time to time until you'll be able to update Android Studio from within the IDE. I encountered the same issues as you but after a while it worked well.

My advise is to wait with the upgrading to `2.0` and stick with your `1.5` version because a lot of people here have problems with Android Studio `2.0` (for now it is kind of buggy, maybe later Google will fixed some issues...).

As an example of my problems with Android Studio 2.0 I've posted recently,  check this:  [After upgrading to Android Studio 2.0, I cannot change the screen orientation in the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514791/after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-0-i-cannot-change-the-screen-orientation-in), but of course it is your decision to upgrade or not :) .

**P.S.** I'm a linux user too.

Comment: Ok then i wait for the next update. Although i still believe it is a general problem with the download page

Comment: My assumption is that they deleted the 2.0-version from server because of these many bugs.

Comment: I'm already regretting for upgrading to 2.0. It has nice features and so on, but it's to buggy.

Answer (score 0):

As this is entirely a new version, you will not be able to update (or upgrade) from within the app. 
You will have to download the installer and install at the same location replacing your Android studio 1.5

I did the same thing and is working for me.

Regards
Vivek

Comment: That's totally wrong. Yesterday I upgraded Android Studio to 2.0 version from within the app.

Comment: Since i use linux i run it directly from the unzipped folder.. And it seems that the link shown in the pop-up directs to the general download-site anyway...